# .htaccess is not working properly

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder named "redirect" and inside it there are 4 files (including .htaccess) namely:

1. .htaccess
2. index.php
3. process.php
4. redirect.php

Now see my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(redirect\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?l=$1 [L]
```

**The error:** The problem is this that .htaccess file is redirecting all the 4 files, in other words you may say that it is redirecting all the files of the folder redirect onto this file "redirect.php".

**What I want:** I want .htaccess in a way so that it is applicable only on the URLs that are like `../redirect.php/1` *(or any other number)* to be parsed via redirect.php file. I don't want the .htaccess to function on the URLs like ../index.php or ../process.php
FYI: I am making a URL shortener website and I hope you know what is its function.

Answer (score 0):

Try including these conditions as well:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
```